# Migrate B2C Tenant Users to other B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have two b2c tenants. One for a production environment and other for a staging environment. I want to migrate all the users from the production tenant to the staging one. And I want to do it periodically to make tests on the staging environment with real data.
I know I can read all the users from on tenant and write them to the other, but when I write the new users they will have new object-ids and that will make my data base inconsistent with the tenant. 
Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Object ids are always unique, I don't think you can get the same ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported. Object IDs are generated by Azure at object creation and can't be duplicated or set by users.